# Closing unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, etiquette, close-reasons

Questions like this:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2295/enhanced-list-and-horizontal-bar

Can we close so that the % answered shows up better ?

Some questions just stay there and the user who asks is a visitor who has an immediate need to get it resolved and never turns back to mark it answered, so the best bet would be to filter out questions that have '-' down votes ?

Please pour in your thoughts!!!!

Answer (score 6):

Hmmm, my gut reaction was no, because we shouldn't moderate just to improve statistics.

However, I think it's an issue that needs to be dealt with on a question by question basis; some questions may not be answered but still have some useful information contained within it or in proposed answers, others, like the one highlighted are of little use to anybody.

For this particular case I would argue that it should be closed as it's not of use to anybody right now, but I think we need to give the OP a little bit longer before doing so. Granted it's probably not a problem they're still trying to solve, but we don't want to disuade new users either—I propose that we wait until the end of the month and then review it.

Comment: I have to reiterate this answer — Closing legitimate questions asked in good faith just to improve your statistics would not be a legitimate use of community moderation.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Lacey, you do NOT moderate the site to fix your start.

However, just like any SE site, the community can moderate the site.  If 5 users close the question, it automatically closes.

So as a user, when closing a question, you can select the reason, if you feel it's too localized/not constructive - go ahead - that's the power you have as a user on SFSE.

[image]